# Can a HTML hidden variable be seen or changed by an end user?

Tags: c#, hidden, asp.net-mvc-views

I am coding a MVC5 internet application where some of my Views have hidden values for the ViewModel.

Here is an example:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)
```

Is this a safe way to store variables that could potentially be sensitive? By sensitive, I mean variables that should not be seen or changed by any user or any javaScript code.

Comment: HiddenFor simply generates an input with type=hidden, so "no".

Comment: use can use session, viewstate view bag etc to hide data from user

Comment: A client like Chrome and Firefox that allows live editing of the data is something you can't really control. You might be able to use session storage for the id since it's small and can be easily cleared.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the end user can see and potentially change the value. All that `HiddenFor` does is render a hidden input tag like so:

```
<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="abc123"/>
```

So, this isn't a safe way to store sensitive data.

A *slightly* better way would be a session variable, but that can still be altered by a more savvy user.

The answer largely depends on just *how* sensitive the data is. Your best bet is probably saving anything sensitive server side to a database or other data store, and only rendering an ID to the client side so you can validate and retrieve then data when needed.

Comment: Cookies could work too. If you encode whatever you write in the cookie

Comment: @RenukaDeshmukh that's true. At a certain level the only way to be sure would be encoding or encrypting the data. Like I said, it depends on how secure the data needs to be.

Comment: Old comment, but an old myth too. Session data is stored server side and is not editable by the user.  Only a reference ID to track the user is stored client side.

Answer (score 0):

The only "safe" way is to not send your variables to the client. That aside, you could look at encrypting your values that you send to the clients and decrypting them when they are posted back.

A hidden field like below will not be readily apparent to the user and changing the value in the hidden field will invalidate the request.

```
<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="GH1k2ji5as2352"/>
```